# Unable to update/refresh select option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select option in my HTML body. I am trying to update the select option when there is a change in select before it.

However, I see in the browser console the following error

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at   $('#plan').selectmenu("refresh");

HTML

```
    <select name="service" id="service" class="default" tabindex="3" onchange="updatePlanInfo(this)">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Service</option> <!-- Example of a hidden dropkick placeholder -->
      <option value="Hadoop">Hadoop</option>
      <option value="NoSQLDB">NOSQLDB</option>
    </select>

    <select name="plan" id="plan" class="default" tabindex="4" >
      <option value=""selected disabled>Plan</option>
      <option value="Free">Free</option>
      <option value="Small">Small</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript

```
    function updatePlanInfo(servicename)
    {
      alert(servicename);

var newOptions = {
  "Option 1": "value1",
  "Option 2": "value2",
  "Option 3": "value3"
};

var $el = $("#plan");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$.each(newOptions, function(value,key) {
  $el.append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", value).text(key));
});

$('#plan').selectmenu("refresh");

    }
```

Comment: where is your `selectmenu` definition goes?

Answer (score 0):

$('').selectmenu() is an jquery ui widget. You need to use jquery ui js file in order to use this widget.

I Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$('#plan').selectmenu("refresh");
```

gives you a script error for three reasons:

1. The `selectmenu` method is [part of the JQuery UI framework](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)
2. According to the error you see in the console, it seems that you have not included this framework in your page.
3. You have to initialize a select element as a `selectmenu` before you can `refresh` it. Like:
   `$("#plan").selectmenu();`

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/unzcxr90/2/).

However, if you don't plan on using the JQuery UI framework with your project, you can simply comment out the line where you attempt to refresh the select element.